# Making a data template - XAML

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a listbox I want to display information in, I bring in variables from a text file and assign them to strings. I want the end result to look like this:

```
"Make: " [Make] "\t" "Model: " [Model] 
"Price: " [Price] "\t" "Mileage: " [Mileage]
```

I have read into the best options, I am using a ToString method at the moment, however I have read up that templates in the XAML would be a better option.

My question: How do I format a datatemplate in the XAML to display the above information and bring in the variables needed?

Comment: Question, are you using MVVM?..if not, its a very good place to start, your answer lies there.https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msgulfcommunity/2013/03/13/understanding-the-basics-of-mvvm-design-pattern/

Comment: I do know the file location and layout, the file contains information regarding the car including the above variables and more, separated by a ',' I have sucessfully taken in these variables and separated into the the names shown above. I dont understand how to make the datatemplate in the XAML to include both the strings and the variables....

Comment: using MVVM allows you to databind, and this is exactly what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd look something like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="Make: "/>
                <Run Text="{Binding Make}"/>
                <Run Text="Model: "/>
                <Run Text="{Binding Model}"/>
                <Run Text="Price:" />
                <Run Text="{Binding Price}"/>
                <Run Text="Mileage:" />
                <Run Text="{Binding Mileage}"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>                
</ListBox>
```

Assuming you have an observable collection of `MyList` built up from your file, which has properties of `Make`, `Model`, etc.

Given your structure here, you may want to consider a `ListView` (like a list but with columns) rather than a list.

Comment: I have a <list> VehicleList would this work for that type of list?

Comment: See if you can have it be an `ObservableCollection<VehicleList>`, assuming your `VehicleList` object is a single entry on the list.  If, on the other hand, you have a custom collection, see if you can get it to implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748365%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 for more info.